# combining two gsap functions into one

Tags: javascript, gsap

I need to change the value of both `anim_img` and `anim_text` in the `scrolltrigger()` function. In theory, everything should be simple, but somehow it does not work out.

```
const anim_img = document.querySelectorAll('.info__block_img');
const anim_text = document.querySelectorAll('.info__block_text');
for (var i = 0; i < anim_text.length; i++) {
  gsap.to(anim_img[i], {
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: anim_text[i],
      markers: true,
      start: '-40% center',
      end: 'center center',
      scrub: 1
    },
    scale: 1,
    opacity: 1
  })
  gsap.to(anim_text[i], {
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: anim_text[i],
      markers: true,
      start: '-40% center',
      end: 'center center',
      scrub: 1
    },
    margin: 0,
    opacity: 1
  })
```

I saw the same values ​​for the variables and decided to combine them into one function, but nothing happened. The videos and documentation say nothing about this.

Comment: anyway i don't think there will be any dependency like that try changing `trigger: anim_text[i]` to `trigger: anim_img[i]` on line 7

Answer (score 0):

For combining both the variable you need to keep both in one loop together when you are adding to `gsap.to`.
here is the possible solution.

```
const anim_img = document.querySelectorAll('.info__block_img');
const anim_text = document.querySelectorAll('.info__block_text');

for (var i = 0; i < anim_text.length; i++) {
  gsap.to([anim_img[i], anim_text[i]], {
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: anim_text[i],
      markers: true,
      start: '-40% center',
      end: 'center center',
      scrub: 1
    },
    opacity: 1,
    onUpdate: function () {
      gsap.to(anim_img[i], {
        scale: 1,
      });
      gsap.to(anim_text[i], {
        margin: 0,
      });
    }
  });
}
```